# C++: How to overcome memory issues using large int/double?

Tags: c++

I am using CERN ROOT 6.22. I am reading ~1000000 rows of data from a file. Whenever the value in the first column >= 40000, I want to continue the loop without reading the values from that row into vectors. Here is a minimal version of my code:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <fstream>
# include <math.h>
# include <iomanip>
# include <cmath>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <cstdlib>
//# include <fstream.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <string>
//# include <dos.h> //For Sleep() 

int main(){
    
    //////Controls//////
    
    char inputFileName[50] = "FridayToAlmostTwoWeeksThursday.dat"; //Name of input file with raw muon data 
    
    int NumOfLines = 1131635; //Number of lines in the input file, used for array index
    int LimitForGood = 40000; //'Time' in which all 'good' data is under. Will only collect data that is under this limit
    
    //////Variables/////
    
    ifstream inFile;
    
    double time_temp;
    
    const int nArray = NumOfLines + 1;
    
    //double time[nArray];
    //double timestamp[nArray];
    vector<double> time;
    vector<double> timestamp;
    
    ////////////////////////
    //////Main Program//////
    
    
    inFile.open(inputFileName,ios::in);
    
    if(inFile.is_open()){
        cout<<"Input File was opened successfully"<<endl;
    }
    
    // Create temporary containers to read data into vectors
    double tempTime = 0;
    double tempTimestamp = 0;
    
    //Main loop filling arrays from file//
    inFile>>tempTime>>tempTimestamp;
    time.push_back(tempTime);
    timestamp.push_back(tempTimestamp);
    cout<<time.at(0)<<setw(20)<<timestamp.at(0)<<endl;
    
    for(int i = 1; i < NumOfLines; i++){
        
        //inFile>>time[i]>>timestamp[i];
        inFile>>tempTime>>tempTimestamp;
        if (tempTime < LimitForGood){
        time.push_back(tempTime);
        timestamp.push_back(tempTimestamp);
        cout<<time[i]<<setw(20)<<timestamp[i]<<endl;
        }
        
    } 
    cout << "Size of vectors: " << time.size() << endl;
    inFile.close();
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

My problem is whenever I use `40000`, I get memory issues:

```
 *** Break *** segmentation violation
```

Yet, if I use a smaller number, such as `400`, the code works fine. Is there a general way to overcome this issue so that I can still check for values under 40000? I am going to have to use large values such as these throughout my code.

Comment: Are you sure that this is due to running out of memory?  Assuming `sizeof(double) == 8` on your platform, this should only take ~18MB of memory (`(8+8)*1131635`).

Comment: If you used `vector::at()` instead of `[ ]` to access the elements, you should see that it is not a memory issue.  Instead you would be thrown an `std::out_of_range` exception.  Your "working" code of 400 or less would also have thrown the exception.

Comment: Unrelated: You should do an inventory of what you are including. `stdlib.h` _and_ `cstdlib` isn't needed. Only include `cstdlib`. Also include `ctime` instead of `time.h` and `cstring` instead of `string.h` etc.

Comment: `cout<<time[i]<<setw(20)<<timestamp[i]<<endl;` -- So here is the question to you -- why didn't you use `at()` here also?  You used it earlier in your program here: `cout<<time.at(0)<<setw(20)<<timestamp.at(0)<<endl;`.  Just doing that would have avoided coming to the wrong conclusion as to what is wrong with the program.

Comment: `time[i]` is only valid if every `if (tempTime < LimitForGood){` so far has succeeded to push something into the `time` vector.  maybe you meant `time[time.size()-1]` or `time.back()` to get the last time in the vector (most recently added).  Or you can keep a second index (not `i`) that only increments when in the _if_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for(int i = 1; i < NumOfLines; i++){        
    inFile>>tempTime>>tempTimestamp;
    if (tempTime < LimitForGood){
        time.push_back(tempTime);
        timestamp.push_back(tempTimestamp);
        cout<<time[i]<<setw(20)<<timestamp[i]<<endl;
    }        
}
```

Before the loop you already pushed one item to the vector, so starting with `i=1` you can use `i` as index after pushing another element to the loop. So far ok, but already on the next iteration you go off the rails:

If in the second entry in the file `tempTime < LimitForGood` is `false` then you are not pushing that entry. On the second iteration (the one that reads the 3rd entry from the file) of the loop `i=2` but there is still only one element in the vector. The next time you add one to the vector `i` will be an invalid index.

Use `back()` instead to get the a reference to the last element:

```
for(int i = 1; i < NumOfLines; i++){        
    inFile>>tempTime>>tempTimestamp;
    if (tempTime < LimitForGood){
        time.push_back(tempTime);
        timestamp.push_back(tempTimestamp);
        cout << time.back() << setw(20) << timestamp.back() << endl;
    }        
}
```

There might be other problems, but reading from an invalid index of the vector can go wrong for a time unnoticed until you try to access a memory address that does not belong to your process. Anyhow, thats just speculations, but for sure the above was wrong and accessing an invalid index of the vector is undefined behavior, aka "anything can happen".